# Gather an array from the user, print the smallest number, highest number, calculate average, and median

Tags: java, arrays, logic, average, median

I am moving along in this program just fine, but as I have progressed I have seemingly made some logic errors that are tough to find & need some help. I have methods that sort the array from least to greatest. Whenever I print the smallest number to the screen it always shows that number as 0 even if I haven't typed any zero. I can get the correct highest number, except for when the user enters the max amount of numbers, then it prints the second highest number. Sometimes I get the correct output for the median, but never get the correct output for the average. Any help is greatly appreciated! I feel like I am close to the correct code, but these errors are giving me a tough time.

```
public static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //change to 100 when done testing
    final int MAXSIZE = 10;
    int[] nums = new int [MAXSIZE];
    int usedSize, indexOfNextSmallest = 0;
    double median, average;

    System.out.println("Please enter each number starting from least to greatest(a negative number will quit input): ");
    usedSize = getNums(nums);

    for (int index = 0; index < nums.length -1; index++) {
        indexOfNextSmallest = getIndexOfSmallest(index, nums);
        interchange(index, indexOfNextSmallest, nums);
    }

    median = medians(nums);
    average = averages(nums);

    System.out.println("The smallest number entered is " + nums[0] + ".");
    System.out.println("The largest number entered is " + nums[nums.length-1] + ".");
    System.out.println("The median is: " + median);
    System.out.println("The average is: " + average);

}

public static int getIndexOfSmallest(int startIndex, int[] nums) {
    int min = nums[startIndex];
    int indexOfMin = startIndex;
    for (int index = startIndex +1; index < nums.length; index++) {
        if (nums[index] < min) {
            min = nums[index];
            indexOfMin = index;
        }
    }
    return indexOfMin;
}

private static void interchange(int index, int indexOfNextSmallest, int[] nums) {
    int temp = nums[index];
    nums[index] = nums [indexOfNextSmallest];
    nums[indexOfNextSmallest] = temp;
}

public static int getNums(int nums[]) {
    int usedSize = 0, userValue = 0;

    while(userValue >= 0 && usedSize < nums.length) {
        nums[usedSize] = userValue;
        userValue = kbd.nextInt();
        usedSize++;
    }
    if(!(userValue >= 0)) {
        --usedSize;
        System.out.println(usedSize + " numbers entered.");
    }
    else if(!(usedSize < nums.length)) {
        System.out.println("Maximum amount of inputs (" + nums.length + ") reached.");
    }

    return usedSize;
}

public static double medians(int nums[]) {
    double median;
    if (nums.length % 2 == 0)
        median = ((double)nums[nums.length / 2] + (double)nums[nums.length / 2 - 1]) / 2;
    else
        median = (double)nums[nums.length / 2];

    return median;

}

public static double averages(int nums[]) {
    double average;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < nums.length; index++){
        sum = sum + nums[index];
    }
    average = ((double)sum / (double)nums.length);

    return average;
}
```

}
This is the output that I am getting if I enter 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -7(the negative is to stop user input(could that be a problem?))

```
Please enter each number starting from least to greatest(a negative number will quit input):
1 2 3 4 5 -7
5 numbers entered.
The smallest number entered is 0.
The largest number entered is 5.
The median is: 0.5
The average is: 1.5
```

The answers I should be getting with correct code is 1, 5, 3.0, & 3.0

Thank you again for any help.

Comment: The reason `averages()` is failing is because the `nums` array is being altered elsewhere in the code.

Comment: would this be the same case for medians()?

Comment: This would be my guess (haven't tested `medians()` though).

Comment: Ok. So the getNums() method is where I am getting the user to enter the numbers for the array...where else could the array be altered?

Comment: I guess theres a chance it could be being altered in one of the methods sorting the array.

Answer (score 2):

Your `medians()` and `averages()` methods look fine.  I would recommend that you get rid of the `getIndexOfSmallest()` and `interchange()` methods.  You only ostensibly need these methods because you are trying to sort.  But I believe the sort is instead altering the array.  Use the following method to find the minimum value:

```
public int getMin(int[] nums) {
    int min = nums[0];

    for (int i=1; i < nums.length; ++i) {
        if (nums[i] < min) {
            min = nums[i];
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```

I will leave it as a homework assignment for you to code a method to find the maximum value.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Would you mind looking at the answer under this? I feel if I combine the two answers I will get the correct min and max solving the problem the answer below gives me.

Comment: You _don't_ need to sort the input array to get the min and max.  Just read the input, and then call `getMin()`, `getMax()`, `medians()`, and `averages()`.

Comment: When testing my program though I ran into a problem. I still get 0 as the smallest number even if I dont enter zero. Any ideas how I could fix this. What if the min number was for example 3?

Comment: Sorry there was a bug in my code.  I answered using a cell phone and only now am I in front of my computer.  You should only pass in an array which has at least one element.

Comment: You're good. I am doing what you said, but the min is always 0 unless I enter the maximum amount of numbers for the array. I have the same code that you wrote, but still get 0. I am lost as to why this is because it should be working right.

Comment: This is probably happening because you have empty slots in the array which default to a value of `0`.  This is what I saw in my test code, until I made certain that the array _only_ contained "real" data.  Check the array in the debugger and you should see this happening.

Comment: Hm, ok. This because of the constant MAXSIZE giving the empty slots 0 i'm guessing?

Comment: If I fix the first problem balwinder told me about, this should fix the issue, correct? Im just a little lost on how do go about doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95506/discussion-between-t3rm3nator-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 2):

The whole thing goes worng in two places:

**The first one**

```
    final int MAXSIZE = 10;
    int[] nums = new int [MAXSIZE];
```

This means that even though the program stopped accepting values after a negative value; all the rest of the array is filled with 0s.

To resolve this, you can choose to use `ArrrayList` instead on int array.

**The second issue**

The existing code for getnums is

```
public static int getNums(int nums[]) {
    int usedSize = 0, userValue = 0;

    while(userValue >= 0 && usedSize < nums.length) {           
        nums[usedSize] = userValue;
        userValue = kbd.nextInt();          
        usedSize++;
    }
    if(!(userValue >= 0)) {
        --usedSize;
        System.out.println(usedSize + " numbers entered.");
    }
    else if(!(usedSize < nums.length)) {
        System.out.println("Maximum amount of inputs (" + nums.length + ") reached.");
    }

    return usedSize;
}
```

Here in the while loop, the statements

```
        nums[usedSize] = userValue;
        userValue = kbd.nextInt();
```

will ensure that the value at num[0] will always be zero(as userValue is initialised to 0) and it won't be fetched from user input.

Instead it should be:

```
while(userValue >= 0 && usedSize < nums.length) {           
        userValue = kbd.nextInt();
        nums[usedSize] = userValue;
        usedSize++;
 }
```

If you take care of these two issues; then the rest of the code should work out fine.

---

**This is what I get when I run the program after updating it for the second issue:**

> Input

```
Please enter each number starting from least to greatest(a negative number will quit input): 
5
8
4
32
-5
```

> Output

```
The smallest number entered is -5.
The largest number entered is 32.
The median is: 0.0
The average is: 4.4
```

Which is correct cause the average and median are calculated for 10 numbers and the rest of the numbers (after entering negative number) are just 0

---

**Update as per comments**

If you just wish to reject the negative number the you can update the while loop in `getnums` method as:

```
    while(userValue >= 0 && usedSize < nums.length) {           
        userValue = kbd.nextInt();
        if(userValue >= 0) {
            nums[usedSize] = userValue;
            usedSize++;
        }
    }
```

Also, the if loop after that shouldn't decrease the value of `usedSize`

```
if(!(userValue >= 0)) {        
        System.out.println(usedSize + " numbers entered.");
    }
```

Comment: Ok I understand what you're saying. I made the change to the second part, but now it is telling me that my lowest number is the - number I entered to stop the input. Which makes sense. But how could I get the code to essentially get rid of the negative in the array? Because all I need the negative for is to quit the user input. & for the constant...should it be moved to the getNums method & instead have the array length set to nums[nums.length]?

Comment: Ok, cool. So when I figure out what to do with the constant, it should run smoothly?

Comment: @T3rm3nator Check the updated answer for handling negative number as well as to print correct values for total numbers entered

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am still trying to practice to make my code more efficient, & you've helped me see what I should've been doing different. However, the negative numbers aren't factored into the min or max methods but still effect the median and average.

Comment: @T3rm3nator Have a look at the updated answer for negative numbers. They shouldn't be now factored into any of the methods

Comment: I wouldnt think they would be, but if I enter an input such as 23, 5, 68, 2, -5.    The answers I get are: "4 numbers entered" (Right) "smallest number is 0" (wrong; should be 2) "largest number is 68" (right) "median is 0.0" (wrong; should be 14) & "average is 9.8" (wrong; should be 24.5)

Comment: @T3rm3nator You are getting those numbers because issue 1 still exists. So you have got 4 numbers (23,5,68,2 -- ignoring the negative one) and 6 zeros. In this case, the minimum will be 0 (remember 6 zeros), largest is 68, median will be 0.0 (which is what you got -- right) and average will be 9.8. To get your answers you would need to either ignore the zeroes in your code or remove them from the array. But what will happen if the user actually enters 0? You need to consider all these scenarios

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95507/discussion-between-t3rm3nator-and-balwinder-singh).